# Why am I running out of RAM when importing 3GB file to Google Colab from Google Drive?

Tags: import, google-colaboratory, ram

I've uploaded my 3.46GB file to my google drive. I am only using 7/15GB on my drive.

Then I mount my drive:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive'
```

And import:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/OP_DTL_GNRL_PGYR2020_P06302023.csv')
df.head()
```

But I keep receiving the error: "Your session crashed after using all available RAM..."

I thought Google Colab comes with 12GM of RAM? I've tried using the GPU and TPU to upload but I still receive the same error.